# How to interactively update default (selected = ) values in R shiny input widgets from external file without using update_Input like functions?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on an app that creates a new data (Excel) file based on user input and also lets the user reload a previously created file, display/update the contents as desired. This, as I understand requires updating the default (selected = ) values in the various input functions.

The app works like this: The user selects the number of pages and fills in data, each page is saved as a worksheet in an Excel file. When the user wants to update the file to add or remove pages, the user loads the excel file from an access restricted folder, and the data from each tab gets populated in each page. The user then edits the input values as appropriate and saves the data.

I am able to use updateSelectInput and similar functions to update the fields. The challenge is, I have about 30 input fields per page and up to 20 pages of it needing 600 update statements. I am looking for a simple and efficient way to accomplish this. Given below is an example that nearly showcases the basic concept of what I am trying to achieve.

```
library(shiny)

Sel <- data.frame(list(x = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length","3" )))

ui <- fluidPage(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("File1", "Load File", multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL, width = NULL,
                buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "No file selected"),
      actionButton("NewValues", "Values from file"), 
      tags$br(),tags$br(),
      selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris), selected = Sel$x[1]),
      selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris), selected = Sel$x[2]),
      selectInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', choices = seq(1:9), selected = Sel$x[3])
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Sel <- eventReactive(input$NewValues, {
    inFile <- input$File1
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
     # The output of eventReactive function will be something equivalent to this: 
     # Sel <- data.frame(list(x = c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length","5" )))
  })

  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When the data (CSV) file is loaded, the `Sel` data frame created from the eventReactive function would be equivalent to this:

```
 Sel <- data.frame(list(x = c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length","5" )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest i could get:

```
library(shiny)

Sel2 <- data.frame(list(x = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length","3" )))

ui <- fluidPage(

  pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("File1", "Load File", multiple = FALSE, accept = NULL, width = NULL,
                buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "No file selected"),
      actionButton("NewValues", "Values from file"), 
      tags$br(),tags$br(),
      uiOutput("select1"),
      #selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris), selected = Sel$x[1]),
      #selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris), selected = Sel$x[2]),
      selectInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', choices = seq(1:9), selected = Sel2$x[3])
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Sel <- eventReactive(input$NewValues, {
    inFile <- input$File1
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    # The output of eventReactive function will be something equivalent to this: 
    # Sel <- data.frame(list(x = c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Length","5" )))
  })

  output$select1<-renderUI({
    element_number<- length(Sel2$x) - 1 
    lapply(1:element_number, function(i) {
      selectInput(inputId=paste0("col",i),paste0("Col ",i),
                choices = names(iris), selected = Sel2$x[i])})}) 

  selectedData <- reactive({
    element_number<- length(Sel2$x) - 1 
    vector <- lapply(1:element_number, function(i) {
      a <- eval(parse(text=paste0("input$col",i)))})
      b <-unlist(strsplit(as.character(vector), ","))
      data <- iris[, b]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

There is a function which is going to automatically create `selectInput`s on base of length of arguments in file which is read (**however length - 1, `(Sel2$x) - 1` , as the last argument is the cluster number** and i could not find easy solution to cope with that, but if the cluster number is always the last argument assgined then it should not be the problem):

```
  output$select1<-renderUI({
    element_number<- length(Sel2$x) - 1 
    lapply(1:element_number, function(i) {
      selectInput(inputId=paste0("col",i),paste0("Col ",i),
                choices = names(iris), selected = Sel2$x[i])})})
```

And further on base of created widgets i was able to subset the data for further analysis:

```
  selectedData <- reactive({
    element_number<- length(Sel2$x) - 1 
    vector <- lapply(1:element_number, function(i) {
      a <- eval(parse(text=paste0("input$col",i)))})
      b <-unlist(strsplit(as.character(vector), ","))
      data <- iris[, b]
  })
```

Comment: That was a great effort. This gives me ideas on minimizing the code length. The one part I did not understand was when I load input parameters from a file (as described in the question)  the selected values that show up in the selectInput and textInput boxes do not get updated from the answer script. Can you kindly enlighten me on that?

Comment: instead of Sel2 in code you should use Sel(). I have just used some example data Sel2 to solve your problem